# How to use two different Info.plists?

Tags: xcode, macos, info.plist

How do I specify different Info.plist files for different targets?

What should I put in the field:  Project Editor/Build Phase/Packaging/Info.plist File ? If I put my own file name there, I get a warning, and my input is ignored.

There are no .plists in Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources (an error I read about in stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Select one of your targets -> Build Settings -> Info.plist File. And in the Info.plist you can specify different Info.plist files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get this warning:  The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/oldmancoyote1/A REFERENCE SYSTEM/D/Developer/Mac osx/Epiphany/EpiphanyWrite2/E2 Submittal Dual/Info.plist'. And, my additions to Info.plist File are ignored.

Comment: Could you share your project somewhere?

Comment: This is a huge project.  Is there some part I can share?

Comment: Try to do same thing on hello world project.

Comment: I did try it on a simple project.  Your suggestion worked fine.  I think there is some problem with the plists themselves.  Thank you